# Search by street name/postcode in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, google-maps

Can anyone help me search by street name in OpenLayers? I essentially want to be able to search for streets/postcodes in OpenLayers in the same way I can search on Google maps. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, its not that easy. You need to put up a search engine like nominatim for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers is like a really good suspension and you are asking for a full-blown car. You have to find data that has what you want (like Openstreetmap), and load it to a queryable data store. Another option is to leverage something like [the mapquest open data apis](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open)

Answer (score 1):

Openlayer Geocoder (ESRI and Geonames) Example

[image]

http://projects.bryanmcbride.com/sandbox/OL_geocode.html#